# Set Color Dark & Light Mode for label background

Tags: swift, option-type, uicolor, ios-darkmode

```
class func setColorLightDarkMode() -> UIColor {
      let aColor = UIColor(named: "StatusBackGroundColor") ?? .gray
      return aColor
}
label.backgroundColor = setColorLightDarkMode()
```

Added Color Assert for `BackGroundColor` and set `AnyAppearance` & `DarkAppearance` with two different color.

set default set to .gray, how to avoid default value .gray
for setting dark & light mode for background Color

Which is best way to to have making  `setColorLightDarkMode` return type optional ? or `UIColor` and set ?? .defaultColor

Comment: I guess I'd do this rather differently, but it's hard to say. First, what *exactly* is your issue? How does your code behave in some way you didn't expect? (Basically, what is calling `setColorLightDarkMode`?) This seems important, as the user actually sets this sort of thing. Second, have you broken down the declaration of `aColor`? It seems like your attempt to set it is failing.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what exactly you want to achieve, however check this [article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dark-mode-support-ios/) for setting custom dark / light colors , default colors etc. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: if you don't want to use optional value .gray you can replace default value by adding exclamation mark at the end of initializing UIColor object e.g UIColor(named: "StatusBackGroundColor")!  if you sure you have added the color asset in Assets.xcassets

Comment: label.backgroundColor will safely accept both an optional or UIColor. If the optional is nil, then the default .clear is used. For simplicity, leave the color as an optional. Otherwise use the default .clear or choose one of the dark/light colors such as  .secondarySystemBackground.